# Extremely High Anonymous VM and App Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a really big problem that I can't handle. My app uses iBeacons to show views and load some pics stored in CoreData, but well, thats not the real question.
I'm loading some pics from parse to core data then retrieved from core data to be displayed.

When i change from one view to another i assume that it can increase, but when i quit the view could be possible to release memory? I don't know it I'm explaining it very well, but i hope you can understand me and help me as much as you can.

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7.1 on my iPad

Now I'm using instruments to try to see what's going on, and this is what i get.

Allocations:
[image: Look at Anonymous VM]
[image: Memory Leaks]
[image: Anonymous VM list]

I think i'm not doing it wrong, loading images like this, dunno what is the problem :_(

```
self.itemsSection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.generalImages1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self fillArraysWithItems:self.itemsSection1 section:@"1"];
    [self fillArraysWithGeneralImages:self.generalImages1 section:@"1"];
    self.itemImages = [NSArray
                       arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithData:self.itemsSection1[0][@"image"]],
                       [UIImage imageWithData:self.itemsSection1[1][@"image"]],
                       [UIImage imageWithData:self.itemsSection1[2][@"image"]],
                       [UIImage imageWithData:self.itemsSection1[3][@"image"]],
                       [UIImage imageWithData:self.itemsSection1[4][@"image"]], nil];
    for (int i=0; i<self.generalImages1.count; i++) {
        [self.itemSliderImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:self.generalImages1[i][@"image"]]];
    }
    generalImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.generalImages1[0][@"image"]];
    self.img_elements.image = generalImage.image;
    self.navBar_title.title = @"Catering";
```

FillArraysWithItems:

```
    -(void)fillArraysWithItems: (NSMutableArray*)item section:(NSString*)section{

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchedRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchedRequest setEntity:entity];

    self.allItemInfo = [[delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchedRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"\n\nAllItems:%@\n", self.allItemInfo);
    for (NSManagedObjectContext *obj in self.allItemInfo) {
        //Save data from CoreData to arrays
        NSLog(@"\n\nObject:\n%@", obj);
        NSString *micro = @"micro_off.png";
        NSString *oven = @"oven_off.png";
        NSString *recycle = @"recycle_off.png";
        NSString *biodeg = @"biodeg_off.png";
        NSString *liquid = @"liquid_off.png";
        NSString *perso = @"perso_off.png";
        NSLog(@"\n\nName:%@\nRef:%@\nPricePack:%@\nUnitPrice:%@\nunitsPack:%@",[obj valueForKey:@"name"], [obj valueForKey:@"reference"],[obj valueForKey:@"pricePack"], [obj valueForKey:@"priceUnity"], [obj valueForKey:@"unitsPack"]);
        NSLog(@"\n\nMicro:%@\nOven:%@\nRecycle:%@\nBiodeg:%@\nLiquid:%@\nPerso:%@\n", [obj valueForKey:@"micro"], [obj valueForKey:@"oven"], [obj valueForKey:@"recycle"], [obj valueForKey:@"bio"], [obj valueForKey:@"liquid"], [obj valueForKey:@"perso"]);

        if ([[obj valueForKey:@"section"] isEqual:section]) {
            if ([[obj valueForKey:@"micro"]  isEqual: @1]) {
                micro = @"micro_on.png";
            }
            if ([[obj valueForKey:@"oven"] isEqual: @1]) {
                oven = @"oven_on.png";
            }
            if ([[obj valueForKey:@"recycle"] isEqual: @1]) {
                recycle = @"recycle_on.png";
            }
            if ([[obj valueForKey:@"bio"] isEqual: @1]) {
                biodeg = @"biodeg_on.png";
            }
            if ([[obj valueForKey:@"liquid"] isEqual: @1]) {
                liquid = @"liquid_on.png";
            }
            if ([[obj valueForKey:@"perso"] isEqual: @1]) {
                perso = @"perso_on.png";
            }
            [item addObject:@{@"name": [obj valueForKey:@"name"],
                              @"pricePack": [obj valueForKey:@"pricePack"],
                              @"priceUnity": [obj valueForKey:@"priceUnity"],
                              @"reference": [obj valueForKey:@"reference"],
                              @"unitsPack": [obj valueForKey:@"unitsPack"],
                              @"micro": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:micro],
                              @"oven": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:oven],
                              @"recycle": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:recycle],
                              @"bio": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:biodeg],
                              @"liquid": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:liquid],
                              @"perso": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:perso],
                              @"image": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[obj valueForKey:@"image"]]}];
        }
    }
    NSError *error;
    BOOL isFetched = [delegate.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    NSLog(@"Arrays successfully filled: %d", isFetched);
}
```

And this is the error I get when [item addObject...

```
    2014-06-18 09:25:50.176 IBKS[383:60b] -[_PFExternalReferenceData stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d51f50
2014-06-18 09:25:50.178 IBKS[383:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_PFExternalReferenceData stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d51f50'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f8f1f0b 0x3a3cece7 0x2f8f5837 0x2f8f4137 0x2f843098 0x3213d13f 0x3213d107 0x3213d0dd 0x3213d0ab 0x322487e5 0xd2fe5 0xa76a5 0x32125a53 0x32125811 0x321cf043 0x3220bc4b 0x3220a57d 0x322095f9 0xa01cb 0x9debf 0x2fdb6e91 0x2fdb1aeb 0x2fdab081 0x2f8bd01d 0x2f8bc397 0x2f8bb001 0x2f825769 0x2f82554b 0x3475f6d3 0x32184891 0x9a5ed 0x3a8ccab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: It is hard to say - where is this code called?  Your fillitems... methods seem to be storing the image as NSData which you then convert to a UIImage - it seems that you should be able to convert this straight to a UIImage in the fill... methods and halve your memory use straight away

Comment: Ofc, but i've tried to convert it like this: Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC. but nothing has changed

Comment: Also, in instruments, show your memory allocation by call tree to see where the memory is being allocated

Comment: im trying it right now @Paulw11, hope this will help, thx

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey! i've tried it but it's crashing here in the fillArraysWithInfo method, i've added to the question so you can see it. Thanks

Comment: i've added the error to the question @Paulw11 Thanks

Comment: Somewhere you are calling `stringByDeletingPathExtension` against an object that you think is a string but is really a Parse data reference.  Set an exception breakpoint to find out where

Comment: No @Paulw11, I'm not calling this in the entire project :S

Comment: I am having a similar problem when opening panorama images from the UIImagePickerViewController. When I do so, the Anonymous VM jumps to 100MB+ and the app gets very jerky until I get killed for the memory. But as I understand it, I cannot control what's in Anonymous VM directly. I tried wrapping my calls to get the image in @autoreleasepool { } blocks, but that doesn't help. Were you able to fix your problem?